# Codility - function alteration

Tags: java

I cam across this codility test, the problem was to spot a bug in the function and adjust it so that it worked properly.

The array passed to the function is {1,3,3} and K =2.  The function is supposed to return false if K is not found in the array, but it is returning true.  You were only allowed to alter 2 lines of code.

```
public static bool solution(int[] A, int K)
    {

        int n = A.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (A[i] + 1 < A[i + 1])
                return false;
        }
        if (A[0] == 1 && A[n - 1] != K)
            return false;
        else
            return true;

    }
```

In normal circumstances I would just rewrite the function given that I know what it is supposed to do:

```
public static bool solution(int[] A, int K)
    {
        int n = A.Length;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (A[i] == K)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here, it seems that the current code already returns `false` with the specified input.

Comment: @EricBouwers Note that `for` does not iterate to the end.

Comment: What should the function do, exactly? How is the task formulated? Should it just work for {1, 3, 3} or for any int array and int K?

Comment: @WindSwept: did you get correct solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this is a solution.

```
public static bool solution(int[] A, int K)
{

    int n = A.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (A[i] + 1 < A[i + 1])
            return false;
    }
    if (A[0] == 1 || A[n - 1] != K)//Change here && to ||
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

okay fellas I got it! Though not 100%, condition was 2 lines I changed 3, so if you see how we could reduce that to two lines shoot:

```
public class Solution {

public boolean solution(int[] A, int K) {
    int n = A.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        if (A[i] + 1 == A[i + 1] && A[i]+1 == K){ // for wouldn't stop at K, now it does.
            // System.out.println("true"); for testing
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (A[0] != 1 || A[n - 1] != K) { //changed && to || for 0 value in array if we don'tcan't have 0 in array then we can keep && and this solution would meet req of 2 lines changed
        // System.out.println("false"); for testing
        return false;
    } else {
        // System.out.println("true"); for testing
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the code below the correct answer :

```
public boolean solution(int[] A, int k) {
    int n = A.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        if (!(A[i] == A[i + 1]) && !(A[i] == A[i + 1] - 1)) {
            System.out.println(A[i] + "-->" + A[i + 1]);
            return false;

        }
    }

    if (A[0] != 1 || A[n - 1] != k) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

if condition defined at first for loop can be changed as below to get the code working (return true if K value matches element of Array)

```
public static bool solution(int[] A, int K)
{

    int n = A.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
    {
        if (A[i] == K) // This is the changed condition 
            return true;
    }
    if (A[0] == 1 || A[n - 1] != K)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}
```

Comment: `A[0] == 1` part seems unnecesary

Comment: yeah, it is but the problem statement had a condition that only 2 lines of code can be changed atmost, so keeping in line with the stated rule, have only corrected the logic

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that you've already changed two lines, sorry. Still, this condition breaks the logic, the code will return true for a={3,3,3} and k = 2.

Comment: It still doesn't work, I'm afraid. It will return false for a={1,2,3} and k= 3

Comment: changed the second if condition (replaced && operator with || operator) , please let me know if this works

Answer (score -1):

this is possible with java 8

you need to do below changes

1 -  change the if condition in the for loop - 
    create a list of type Integer - and then check contains 
      note - list of int will not work - the contains will not work on it

2 -  the second return statement to return true

and that is how can you get it done by changing just 2 lines

```
public static  boolean sol (int[] a , int k){

    int n = a.length;

    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        if(! Arrays.stream( a ).boxed().collect( Collectors.toList() ).contains(k)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    if(a[0]!=1 && a[n-1]!=k){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```